# ajax form submit not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using jquery.form.js (version: 2.84) and in the below code, I see that it's getting stuck just before $('imageform').ajaxSubmit.. If I remove preventDefault, the form gets submitted as usual and the page gets refreshed. When preventDefault is present, I do see the loader.gif, but in the server side I do not see any data and also the alert is never fired..

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener($('photoimg'), 'change', function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); // <-- important
            $("preview").innerHTML = ("<img src=\"loader.gif\" alt=\"Uploading....\"></img>");
            $('imageform').ajaxSubmit({
                target: 'preview'
            });
            alert('after submit');
        });
```

I am also using a function as below and that's why I am using $('imageform') and not $('#imageform')...

```
function $(element) {
  return document.getElementById(element);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$` function is clobbering the meaning of that same variable for jQuery. You could mess around with lots of compatibility stuff in jQuery, or take the simple route: rename your `$` function to something else, or just call `document.getElementById()` straight out since your function is only saving you from typing out that call. Or, better yet, use jQuery to take care of that call.

Answer (score 3):

No, because you've overwritten `$` with the `getElementById` function.

```
$('imageform').ajaxSubmit
```

will execute `ajaxSubmit` on the DOM element, where you need a jQuery object. You'd either need to remove your `$` or use:

```
jQuery('#imageform').ajaxSubmit
```

---

`$("#foo")` is not the same as `document.getElementById("foo")`.

- The jQuery function returns a jQuery object which has all the jQuery functions like `.bind` and `.ajaxSubmit` present.
- `document.getElementById`, on the other hand, returns a naked DOM element which does not have any functions of jQuery.

The jQuery object is like an array of DOM elements, so:

```
$("#foo")[0] === document.getElementById("foo")
```